# How do I add .gif file to EXPO slash screen

Tags: react-native, expo

I would like to add a .gif to my EXPO project.

I have tried

```
  "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/images/logonamenew.gif",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
```

This is what I have now

```
  "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/images/logonamenew.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
```

It throws an error but works on my local but not when I deploy to the store.

Comment: Thank you. I followed the link and found a work around. https://docs.expo.io/versions/v27.0.0/sdk/app-loading/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**From Expo Forum** : we deprecated the loading key in app.json a long time ago because you it wasn’t possible to make native splash screens with it. if a gif worked in your case it would only have worked within the expo client or after the actual splash screen was dismissed on ios/android. the splash api uses pngs only docs.expo.io/versions/v27.0.0/workflow read more in docs.expo.io/versions/v27.0.0/guides/splash-screens **Original post : forums.expo.io/t/splash-screen-gifs/9418**